# Best web/app server to host multiple low hit rails/sinatra apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webserver, hosting

I need to host a lot of simple rails/sinatra/padrino applications of different ruby versions each with 0..low hits per day. They belong to different owners and should be well isolated from each other.

When an app is hit it should respond in reasonably short time, but I expect several simultaneous visitors are hitting the same site to be a rare case.

I'm going to create separate os user for each application. Surely I'd like to put them as many per server as it's possible. Thus I need to choose the web server with the lowest memory footprint, which can run applications on behalf of different users with different ruby versions and gemsets.

I consider webrick,nginx+passenger,thin,apache+passenger. I suppose the reliability of all choices is sufficient for such a job, and while performance isn't an issue, the memory consumption is.

I found many posts regarding performance issues, but most of them discuss the performance tuning and issues. I couldn't find a comparison of web servers memory usage when idle.

Is "in process" webrick the best choice? Which one would you choose for that job?

And I couldn't figure out how to resolve subdomains to application ports with webrick. Shall I use nginx or apache for that?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have much experience with hosting myself, but using Webrick for production is not a good idea I think. You can also check out mongrel which I saw used in production. In most cases though you will probably want to choose between thin and unicorn. Check out this http://cmelbye.github.com/2009/10/04/thin-vs-unicorn.html or google around. Good luck :-)

Comment: Added Mongrel to the long list. Seems I shouild perform some smoke tests by myself. Thanks for reply !

Comment: You can use the 'ab' tool from Apache SF to simulate a stress test on your application. On debian the package is called apache2-utils. Using mongrel I was getting only about half the performance of a pure apache server, while webrick was 10 times slower than mongrel! It's always hard to make a good benchmark with servers but this is already a very notable result. If you do not expect high load on your application though then you do not have to choose carefully. Apache or Nginx + Mongrel should be a very good fit.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Heroku? Its free and gets you out of the hassle of server configuration and maintenance.

Comment: I need to utilize my server resources providing simple hosting for site community members. Heroku doesn't support sinatra/padrino, does it?

Comment: Heroku supports sinatra...see: http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2009/3/5/32_deploy_merb_sinatra_or_any_rack_app_to_heroku/ Not sure about padrino, but I did this http://www.padrinorb.com/guides/blog-tutorial Search for Heroku in that article. For the most part if its rack based, then Heroku can host it.

Comment: ok, I see. Thanks.
but I still want to setup it from the scratch.